# Remove Tags from Products in Woocommerce using PHP

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, tags, product

I want to remove tags from products in WooCommerce

```
function prefix_show_is_products() {
    $products = wc_get_products(array(
        'tag' => array('weekly')
    ));

// CODE TO REMOVE 'weekly' from the products

}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should use https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remove_object_terms/

```
wp_remove_object_terms($product->get_id(), 'weekly', 'product_tag');
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove all tags

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product', 'remove_all_product_tags_on_single_product');
    
    function remove_all_product_tags_on_single_product() {
        // Checking if the current page is a product page
        if (is_product()) {
            // We receive the current product
            global $product;
    
            // Checking whether the product is an object of the WC_Product class
            if ($product instanceof WC_Product) {
                // We get the product ID
                $product_id = $product->get_id();
    
                // Remove all product tags
                wp_remove_object_terms($product_id, get_terms('product_tag', array('fields' => 'ids')), 'product_tag');
            }
        }
    }
```

WooCommerce v8.3.1

Removes the "weekly" tag.

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product', 'remove_specific_tag_after_single_product');

function remove_specific_tag_after_single_product() {
    // Checking if the current page is a product page
    if (is_product()) {
        // We receive the current product
        global $product;

        // Checking whether the product is an object of the WC_Product class
        if ($product instanceof WC_Product) {
            // We get the product ID
            $product_id = $product->get_id();

            // Removing a specific 'weekly' tag from a product
            wp_remove_object_terms($product_id, 'weekly', 'product_tag');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome! Thank you for contributing an answer. This is just a note to help you improve your answers. To help future users better understand your answer please provide an explanation with your code blocks. For example, you could explain why your solution works, or how your approach is different from other answers.